# Remove character from string if it starts with that character?

Tags: ruby, string

How can I remove the very first "1" from any string if that string starts with a "1"?

```
"1hello world" => "hello world"
"112345" => "12345"
```

I'm thinking of doing

```
string.sub!('1', '') if string =~ /^1/
```

but I' wondering there's a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to remove the first character from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Why not just include the regex in the `sub!` method?

```
string.sub!(/^1/, '')
```

Answer (score 30):

As of Ruby 2.5 you can use [delete_prefix](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix) or delete_prefix! to achieve this in a readable manner.

In this case `"1hello world".delete_prefix("1")`.

More info here:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/10/10-new-features-in-ruby-2-5/

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12694

```
'invisible'.delete_prefix('in') #=> "visible"
'pink'.delete_prefix('in') #=> "pink"
```

N.B. you can also use this to remove items from the end of a string with delete_suffix and delete_suffix!

```
'worked'.delete_suffix('ed') #=> "work"
'medical'.delete_suffix('ed') #=> "medical"
```

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13665

I've answered in a little more detail (with benchmarks) here: [What is the easiest way to remove the first character from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string#answer-46958806)

Answer (score 8):

if you're going to use regex for the match, you may as well use it for the replacement

```
string.sub!(%r{^1},"")
```

BTW, the `%r{}` is just an alternate syntax for regular expressions.  You can use %r followed by any character e.g. `%r!^1!`.

Comment: "BTW, the %r{} syntax for regular expressions allows you to avoid escaping / within the expression." - But now you have two characters that you need to escape instead of one but the point is moot since none of the characters in question even appear in the pattern.

Comment: It's just a subjective preference.  I'd argue that / is a more common character than either {}.  My BTW was an explanation in case the OP hadn't seen %r{} syntax before.

Answer (score 3):

Careful using `sub!(/^1/,'')` ! In case the string doesn't match `/^1/` it will return `nil`. You should probably use `sub` (without the bang).

Comment: No, it will *return* nil in that case, but the original string will remain unchanged. If you just use `sub`, you will have to do the longer string = string.sub(/^/, '').

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be more optimised: [What is the easiest way to remove the first character from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string)

`string[0] = '' if string[0] == '1'`

Comment: Don't know about optimised, but this seems like the most readable to solution to me. I must be just weird finding regex solutions ugly!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post a tiny improvement to the otherwise excellent answer by Zach. The `^` matches the beginning of every *line* in Ruby regex. This means there can be multiple matches per string. Kenji asked about the beginning of the string which means they have to use this regex instead:

```
string.sub!(/\A1/, '')
```

Compare [this - multiple matches](http://rubular.com/r/FIaX2yDBA1) with [this - one match](http://rubular.com/r/8Fnzm57AtD).