# What is the easiest way to remove the first character from a string?

Tags: ruby, string

Example:

```
[12,23,987,43
```

What is the fastest, most efficient way to remove the "`[`",
using maybe a `chop()` but for the first character?

Comment: I edited my answer, so it might be possible to change your selected answer. See if you can award it to Jason Stirk's answer since his is the fastest, and is very readable.

Comment: Use str[1..-1], its fastest according to the answers below.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.5 you can use `delete_prefix`and `delete_prefix!` - [more details below](/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string#answer-46958806). I've not had the time to benchmark, but will do soon!

Comment: Update: I've benchmarked the new methods (`delete_prefix` \ `delete_prefix!`) and they're pretty fast. The don't quite pip the previous favourites for speed, but readability means they're great new options to have!

Answer (score 251, accepted):

I kind of favor using something like:

```
asdf = "[12,23,987,43"
asdf[0] = '' 

p asdf
# >> "12,23,987,43"
```

---

I'm always looking for the fastest and most readable way of doing things:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 1_000_000

puts RUBY_VERSION

STR = "[12,23,987,43"

Benchmark.bm(7) do |b|
  b.report('[0]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[0] = '' } }
  b.report('sub') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".sub(/^\[+/, "") } }

  b.report('gsub') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".gsub(/^\[/, "") } }
  b.report('[1..-1]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[1..-1] } }
  b.report('slice') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".slice!(0) } }
  b.report('length') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[1..STR.length] } }

end
```

Running on my Mac Pro:

```
1.9.3
              user     system      total        real
[0]       0.840000   0.000000   0.840000 (  0.847496)
sub       1.960000   0.010000   1.970000 (  1.962767)
gsub      4.350000   0.020000   4.370000 (  4.372801)
[1..-1]   0.710000   0.000000   0.710000 (  0.713366)
slice     1.020000   0.000000   1.020000 (  1.020336)
length    1.160000   0.000000   1.160000 (  1.157882)
```

---

Updating to incorporate one more suggested answer:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 1_000_000

class String
  def eat!(how_many = 1)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
  end

  def first(how_many = 1)
    self[0...how_many]
  end

  def shift(how_many = 1)
    shifted = first(how_many)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
    shifted
  end
  alias_method :shift!, :shift
end

class Array
  def eat!(how_many = 1)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
  end
end

puts RUBY_VERSION

STR = "[12,23,987,43"

Benchmark.bm(7) do |b|
  b.report('[0]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[0] = '' } }
  b.report('sub') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".sub(/^\[+/, "") } }

  b.report('gsub') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".gsub(/^\[/, "") } }
  b.report('[1..-1]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[1..-1] } }
  b.report('slice') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".slice!(0) } }
  b.report('length') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[1..STR.length] } }
  b.report('eat!') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".eat! } }
  b.report('reverse') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".reverse.chop.reverse } }
end
```

Which results in:

```
2.1.2
              user     system      total        real
[0]       0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.295054)
sub       0.630000   0.000000   0.630000 (  0.631870)
gsub      2.090000   0.000000   2.090000 (  2.094368)
[1..-1]   0.230000   0.010000   0.240000 (  0.232846)
slice     0.320000   0.000000   0.320000 (  0.320714)
length    0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.341918)
eat!      0.460000   0.000000   0.460000 (  0.452724)
reverse   0.400000   0.000000   0.400000 (  0.399465)
```

---

And another using `/^./` to find the first character:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 1_000_000

class String
  def eat!(how_many = 1)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
  end

  def first(how_many = 1)
    self[0...how_many]
  end

  def shift(how_many = 1)
    shifted = first(how_many)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
    shifted
  end
  alias_method :shift!, :shift
end

class Array
  def eat!(how_many = 1)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
  end
end

puts RUBY_VERSION

STR = "[12,23,987,43"

Benchmark.bm(7) do |b|
  b.report('[0]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[0] = '' } }
  b.report('[/^./]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[/^./] = '' } }
  b.report('[/^\[/]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[/^\[/] = '' } }
  b.report('sub+') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".sub(/^\[+/, "") } }
  b.report('sub') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".sub(/^\[/, "") } }
  b.report('gsub') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".gsub(/^\[/, "") } }
  b.report('[1..-1]') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[1..-1] } }
  b.report('slice') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".slice!(0) } }
  b.report('length') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43"[1..STR.length] } }
  b.report('eat!') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".eat! } }
  b.report('reverse') { N.times { "[12,23,987,43".reverse.chop.reverse } }
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >> 2.1.5
# >>               user     system      total        real
# >> [0]       0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.270165)
# >> [/^./]    0.430000   0.000000   0.430000 (  0.432417)
# >> [/^\[/]   0.460000   0.000000   0.460000 (  0.458221)
# >> sub+      0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.590284)
# >> sub       0.590000   0.000000   0.590000 (  0.596366)
# >> gsub      1.880000   0.010000   1.890000 (  1.885892)
# >> [1..-1]   0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.223045)
# >> slice     0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.299175)
# >> length    0.320000   0.000000   0.320000 (  0.325841)
# >> eat!      0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.409306)
# >> reverse   0.390000   0.000000   0.390000 (  0.393044)
```

---

Here's another update on faster hardware and a newer version of Ruby:

```
2.3.1
              user     system      total        real
[0]       0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.204307)
[/^./]    0.390000   0.000000   0.390000 (  0.387527)
[/^\[/]   0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.360400)
sub+      0.490000   0.000000   0.490000 (  0.492083)
sub       0.480000   0.000000   0.480000 (  0.487862)
gsub      1.990000   0.000000   1.990000 (  1.988716)
[1..-1]   0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.181673)
slice     0.260000   0.000000   0.260000 (  0.266371)
length    0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.267651)
eat!      0.400000   0.010000   0.410000 (  0.398093)
reverse   0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.344077)
```

---

> Why is gsub so slow?

After doing a search/replace, `gsub` has to check for possible additional matches before it can tell if it's finished. `sub` only does one and finishes. Consider `gsub` like it's a minimum of two `sub` calls.

Also, it's important to remember that `gsub`, and `sub` can also be handicapped by poorly written regex which match much more slowly than a sub-string search. If possible anchor the regex to get the most speed from it. There are answers here on Stack Overflow demonstrating that so search around if you want more information.

Comment: It's important to note that this will only work in Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.8, this will remove the first *byte* from the string, *not* the first character, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: +1: I **always** forget that to a string-position you can assign not only a single character, but also you can insert a substring. Thanks!

Comment: `"[12,23,987,43".delete "["`

Comment: That deletes it from all positions, which isn't what the OP wanted: "...for the first character?".

Comment: what about "[12,23,987,43".shift ?

Comment: "`what about "[12,23,987,43".shift ?`"? What about `"[12,23,987,43".shift
NoMethodError: undefined method `shift' for "[12,23,987,43":String`?

Comment: Why gsub is so slow?

Comment: See the added info in the answer.

Answer (score 321):

Similar to Pablo's answer above, but a shade cleaner :

```
str[1..-1]
```

Will return the array from 1 to the last character.

```
'Hello World'[1..-1]
 => "ello World"
```

Comment: +1 Take a look at the benchmark results I added to my answer. You've got the fastest run-time, plus I think it's very clean.

Comment: What about the performance of `str[1,]` compared to the above?

Comment: @Bohr: `str[1,]` return you the 2nd character since the range is `1:nil`. You'd need to provide the actual calculated length, or something guaranteeded to be higher than length, like, `str[1,999999]` (use int_max of course) to get the whole tail. `[1..-1]` is cleaner and probably faster, since you don't need to operate on length manually (see the [1..length] in the benchmark)

Comment: Very nice solution. By the way if one wants to remove first and last characters: `str[1..-2]`

Answer (score 58):

### Ruby 2.5+

As of Ruby 2.5 you can use `delete_prefix` or `delete_prefix!` to achieve this in a readable manner.

In this case `"[12,23,987,43".delete_prefix("[")`.

More info here:

- [Official docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix)
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/10/10-new-features-in-ruby-2-5/
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12694

```
'invisible'.delete_prefix('in') #=> "visible"
'pink'.delete_prefix('in') #=> "pink"
```

N.B. you can also use this to remove items from the end of a string with `delete_suffix` and `delete_suffix!`

```
'worked'.delete_suffix('ed') #=> "work"
'medical'.delete_suffix('ed') #=> "medical"
```

- [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix-21)
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13665

Edit:

Using the Tin Man's benchmark setup, it looks pretty quick too (under the last two entries `delete_p` and `delete_p!`). Doesn't *quite* pip the previous faves for speed, though is very readable.

```
2.5.0
              user     system      total        real
[0]       0.174766   0.000489   0.175255 (  0.180207)
[/^./]    0.318038   0.000510   0.318548 (  0.323679)
[/^\[/]   0.372645   0.001134   0.373779 (  0.379029)
sub+      0.460295   0.001510   0.461805 (  0.467279)
sub       0.498351   0.001534   0.499885 (  0.505729)
gsub      1.669837   0.005141   1.674978 (  1.682853)
[1..-1]   0.199840   0.000976   0.200816 (  0.205889)
slice     0.279661   0.000859   0.280520 (  0.285661)
length    0.268362   0.000310   0.268672 (  0.273829)
eat!      0.341715   0.000524   0.342239 (  0.347097)
reverse   0.335301   0.000588   0.335889 (  0.340965)
delete_p  0.222297   0.000832   0.223129 (  0.228455)
delete_p!  0.225798   0.000747   0.226545 (  0.231745)
```

Answer (score 57):

We can use slice to do this:

```
val = "abc"
 => "abc" 
val.slice!(0)
 => "a" 
val
 => "bc"
```

Using `slice!` we can delete any character by specifying its index.

Comment: This elegant ```slice!(0)``` really should be the selected answer, as using ```asdf[0] = '' ``` to remove the first character is ridiculous (just like using gsub with regex and shooting a fly with a howitzer).

Comment: While it might seem unintuitive on the surface, `[]=` doesn't require as much underlying C code, where `slice!` requires additional work. That adds up. The argument might be "Which is more readable?" I find using `[]=` readable, but I'm coming from a C --> Perl background which probably colors my thinking. Java developers would probably think it's less readable. Either is an acceptable way to accomplish the task as long as it's easily understood and maintainable and doesn't load the CPU unduly.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how we can measure up if a function takes much CPU load in ROR? or should we use execution time difference in milli or nanoseconds?

Answer (score 18):

I prefer this:

```
str = "[12,23,987,43"
puts str[1..-1]
>> 12,23,987,43
```

Comment: You might want to check other answers before repeating them. This was already suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614642/128421

Answer (score 14):

If you always want to strip leading brackets:

```
"[12,23,987,43".gsub(/^\[/, "")
```

If you just want to remove the first character, and you know it won't be in a multibyte character set:

```
"[12,23,987,43"[1..-1]
```

or

```
"[12,23,987,43".slice(1..-1)
```

Comment: I'd use `"[12,23,987,43".sub(/^\[+/, "")` instead of `gsub(/^\[/, "")`. The first lets the regex engine find all matches then they're replaced in one action and results in about a 2x improvement in speed with Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Since we're dealing with strings, should this be `gsub(/\A\[/, "") `?

Answer (score 8):

Inefficient alternative:

```
str.reverse.chop.reverse
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy way:

```
str = "[12,23,987,43"

removed = str[1..str.length]
```

Awesome way:

```
class String
  def reverse_chop()
    self[1..self.length]
  end
end

"[12,23,987,43".reverse_chop()
```

(Note: prefer the easy way :) )

Comment: If you want to preserve the "chop" semantics you could just `"[12,23,987,43".reverse.chop.reverse`

Comment: that is a pretty big performance overhead just to strip one char

Comment: why not use [1..-1] rather than [1..self.length] ?

Comment: Monkey patching example is pretty off for this question, it is just irrelevant and ugly IMO.

Answer (score 4):

For example :  a = "One Two Three"

```
1.9.2-p290 > a = "One Two Three"
 => "One Two Three" 

1.9.2-p290 > a = a[1..-1]
 => "ne Two Three" 

1.9.2-p290 > a = a[1..-1]
 => "e Two Three" 

1.9.2-p290 > a = a[1..-1]
 => " Two Three" 

1.9.2-p290 > a = a[1..-1]
 => "Two Three" 

1.9.2-p290 > a = a[1..-1]
 => "wo Three"
```

In this way you can remove one by one first character of the string.

Comment: This is the same as [Jason Stirk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3614642/128421) only his was submitted many months before.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @the-tin-man for putting together the benchmarks!

Alas, I don't really like any of those solutions. Either they require an extra step to get the result (`[0] = ''`, `.strip!`) or they aren't very semantic/clear about what's happening (`[1..-1]`: "Um, a range from 1 to negative 1? Yearg?"), or they are slow or lengthy to write out (`.gsub`, `.length`).

What we are attempting is a 'shift' (in Array parlance), but returning the remaining characters, rather than what was shifted off. Let's use our Ruby to make this possible with strings! We can use the speedy bracket operation, but give it a good name, and take an arg to specify how much we want to chomp off the front:

```
class String
  def eat!(how_many = 1)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
  end
end
```

But there is more we can do with that speedy-but-unwieldy bracket operation. While we are at it, for completeness, let's write a `#shift` and `#first` for String (why should Array have all the fun‽‽), taking an arg to specify how many characters we want to remove from the beginning:

```
class String
  def first(how_many = 1)
    self[0...how_many]
  end

  def shift(how_many = 1)
    shifted = first(how_many)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
    shifted
  end
  alias_method :shift!, :shift
end
```

Ok, now we have a good clear way of pulling characters off the front of a string, with a method that is consistent with `Array#first` and `Array#shift` (which really should be a bang method??). And we can easily get the modified string as well with `#eat!`. Hm, should we share our new `eat!`ing power with Array? Why not!

```
class Array
  def eat!(how_many = 1)
    self.replace self[how_many..-1]
  end
end
```

Now we can:

```
> str = "[12,23,987,43" #=> "[12,23,987,43"
> str.eat!              #=> "12,23,987,43"
> str                   #=> "12,23,987,43"

> str.eat!(3)           #=> "23,987,43"
> str                   #=> "23,987,43"

> str.first(2)          #=> "23"
> str                   #=> "23,987,43"

> str.shift!(3)         #=> "23,"
> str                   #=> "987,43"

> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]     #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
> arr.eat!              #=> [2, 3, 4, 5] 
> arr                   #=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That's better!

Comment: I remember a discussion years ago in Perl forums about such a function with the name of `chip()` instead of `chop()` (and `chimp()` as the analog of `chomp()`).

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "[12,23,987,43"

str[0] = ""
```

Comment: It's important to note that this will only work in Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.8, this will remove the first *byte* from the string, *not* the first character, which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
  def bye_felicia()
    felicia = self.strip[0] #first char, not first space.
    self.sub(felicia, '')
  end
end
```

Comment: What did Felicia do to you to deserve this code Haiku?

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
str = 'string'
n = 1  #to remove first n characters

str[/.{#{str.size-n}}\z/] #=> "tring"
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a nice solution to be `str.delete(str[0])` for its readability, though I cannot attest to it's performance.

Answer (score 0):

> list = [1,2,3,4]
>   list.drop(1)
>
> `# => [2,3,4]`

List drops one or more elements from the start of the array, does not mutate the array, and returns the array itself instead of the dropped element.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
str = 'string'    
str.tap{|k| k[0] = ''} = 'tring' 
# tap returns the variable that called it 
# but takes a block that allows for modification of said variable in place.
# useful trick for many other things
```