# Remove first 4 characters from a string

Tags: sql, ruby

Through a bunch of `if` statements, I'm concatenating a string to be used as a SQL statement.  The first 3 characters of this string will invariably be "OR ".  How can I efficiently remove these first 4 characters.

```
example:
      sql = " OR tennis = TRUE OR basetball = TRUE"
      if condition sql = sql + " OR racquetball = TRUE"
```

So I need to remove the "OR" and 2 spaces at the beginning of whatever string is created.

Thank you for your time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string/3614592#3614592 has benchmarks showing how to strip the first character from a string. It's easy to adjust the fastest method to handle the first four characters. Hint: Using `String#[range]` is fastest and instead of stripping what you don't want, just grab what you really need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be better to just join things together in the end:

```
sql = [ ]

sql << 'tennis = TRUE'
sql << 'baseball = TRUE'

if (condition)
  sql << 'racquetball = TRUE'
end

sql = sql.join(' OR ')
```

You can also reduce redundancy by remapping things:

```
sports = [ :tennis, :baseball ]

sql = sports.collect { |s| "#{s} = TRUE" }.join(' OR ')
```

If you're intent on trimming off the first four letters:

```
sql = " OR x OR y"
sql.slice!(" OR ")
sql
# => "x OR y"
```

Comment: I'm new to SQL, I did not even realize that was an option.  Is this more efficient or just easier?

Comment: It's usually better to keep things as abstract as possible before boiling it down to a query. Using a layer like ActiveRecord or [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) is usually a lot less messy, so use that if you can. Unless you're doing something intense, manipulating the query string will be near zero cost, so it's not worth worrying about optimizations here. Just go with what's easiest to read.

Comment: I'm doing this with a Rails application and I couldn't find an activerecord "or" function

Comment: It looks like you've got a problem with [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and you've violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) if you have columns like this, they're working against you and making it harder to do than it should be. A proper relational structure would make this pretty easy by comparison. For example, a join table: `User has_many :sports, through: sport_associations`.

Comment: The feature associated with those fields started off much simpler at the time. But you're probably right, I should address that now.  Thank you for the time