# Is there a Ruby slice that's more like a chop?

Tags: ruby

`chop` cuts off the last character and returns the remaining string:

```
irb(main):011:0> "hello world".chop
=> "hello worl"
```

`slice` can be used to cut off the first character

```
irb(main):013:0> str = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
irb(main):014:0> str.slice!(0)
=> "h"
irb(main):015:0> str
=> "ello world"
```

Is there a Ruby method that cuts off the first character but then returns the rest of the string? So it would look like

```
irb(main):011:0> "hello world".some_method
=> "ello world"
```

Comment: As of Ruby 2.5 you can use `delete_prefix` (or the bang equivalent). [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string#answer-46958806).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are couple of ways:

```
> str = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
> str[1..-1]
=> "ello world"
> str = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
> str.slice(1..-1)
=> "ello world"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun way:

```
> str = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
> str.reverse.chop.reverse
=> "ello world"
```

Comment: I imagine an actual ninja flipping the string, giving it a quick chop and flipping it once more.

Comment: While it will do what the OP asked, it's also going to waste CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Another fun (but distructive) way:

```
"hello world".tap { |s| s.slice!(0) }
  #=> "ello world"
```

Comment: Hi Cary, I published two gems [dom](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) and [manager](https://rubygems.org/gems/manager). Please take a look at them if they sound interesting.

Comment: @sawa, thanks, I bookmarked them, but won't get to them until and if I understand more than just pure Ruby. (I don't even know HTML.)