# How remove first 24 characters from log using gsub?

Tags: ruby, logstash, gsub

How do I remove the first 24 characters using `gsub`?

```
2016-08-03 09:49:07,701 [DEBUG] Rector: Common\BasePage, OnInit BEGIN.
```

I want only the following:

```
[DEBUG] Rector: Common\BasePage, OnInit BEGIN
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]". We'd like to see your effort toward solving the problem, without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you. Also, why does it have to be `gsub`? There are better ways to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3614389/128421 is closely related.

Answer (score 2):

```
line = "2016-08-03 09:49:07,701 [DEBUG] Rector: Common\BasePage, OnInit BEGIN."
```

To remove everything before the first `[`:

```
# Note the use of #sub instead of #gsub, as it will only match once
line.sub /\A[^\[]*/, ''
# => "[DEBUG] Rector: CommonBasePage, OnInit BEGIN."
```

You can also index with a regular expression to get everything from the first `[`:

```
line[/\[.*/]
# => "[DEBUG] Rector: CommonBasePage, OnInit BEGIN."
```

If you know that the timestamp prefix is always 24 characters long, use a slice:

```
line[24..-1]
# => "[DEBUG] Rector: CommonBasePage, OnInit BEGIN."
```

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` isn't really a good choice for removing n characters at the start of a string. Instead of doing a search and replace to take out characters, you should simply extract the characters and move on.

The simplest way to remove characters is to assign to a string slice:

```
str = 'foo bar'
str[0, 4] = ''
str # => "bar"
```

Alternately, you can slice and extract the characters from the string:

```
str = 'foo bar'
str[4 .. -1] # => "bar"
```

If you wanted to slow your code because you found you weren't using enough CPU time, you could use a regex:

```
str = 'foo bar'
str[/^.{4}(.+)/, 1] # => "bar"
```

If you *insisted* on using `gsub`:

```
str = 'foo bar'
str.gsub(/^.{4}/, '') # => "bar"
```

however, using `gsub` for that is not as fast, or efficient, as `sub` which would do the same:

```
str = 'foo bar'
str.sub(/^.{4}/, '') # => "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes first 24 characters by `gsub`.

```
'2016-08-03 09:49:07,701 [DEBUG] Rector: Common\BasePage, OnInit BEGIN.'.gsub(/\A.{24}/, '')
# => "[DEBUG] Rector: Common\\BasePage, OnInit BEGIN."
```