# ruby, how to remove the first part of string?

Tags: ruby

This is my first time posting in this forum, I am doing some selenium webdriver testing, I collected some data from an html UI, put it in an array:

```
consents = $driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//*[@id='main-display']/div[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[7]//i")
```

, then I processed the array with map :

```
consent_values = consents.map { |consent| consent.attribute('class')}
```

printing the array I got :

```
["fa fa-check-circle", "fa fa-circle-thin", "fa fa-check-circle", "fa fa-circle-thin", "fa fa-circle-thin", "fa fa-check-circle", "fa fa-circle-thin", "fa fa-circle-thin", "fa fa-check-circle,....]
```

1) Is there a way to do in the map to remove "fa" from all strings in the array ?

2) How about changing the strings "fa fa-check-circle" to be true and "fa fa-circle-thin" to be false so I will get :
[true,false,true,....]

Thanks,

Comment: 1) One way to do it is by using [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-sub) with a [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html) as `pattern`. 2) What prevents you do that?

Comment: I got it, I used string[N..-1] , was wondering if can change the strings to true or false in the map transformation.

Comment: There's a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614389/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-character-from-a-string/46958806#46958806) that goes into detail on removing the start of a string. Might find it good reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically 2) eliminates the necessity of 1), so here you go:

```
consent_values = consents.map do |consent|
  case consent.attribute('class')
  when "fa fa-check-circle" then true
  when "fa fa-circle-thin" then false
  else nil
  end
end
```

To remove `"fa "` prefix from the string one might use `String#[]`:

```
"fa fa-check-circle"[/(?<=\Afa ).*/]
#⇒ "fa-check-circle"
```

Comment: I like this answer too, I will go try it.

Comment: @Fatna This one has the clear answer for you because you can completely eliminate one step.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with `String#[]`. Informative as ever, +1. (I also like 2.5.0's [delete_prefix](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix) for readability.)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[N..-1]
```

This worked for me. thanks anyway, I hope I will interact with this forum lot.

Comment: Hi, Have a look at @mudasobwa 's answer, he has written an answer which actually reduces one step for you!